# Recovering Stage3D context after viewing iAd using Starling and Air for iOS

Tags: air, air-native-extension, starling-framework, iad

I have an app using Starling and a native extension for iAds (Milkman Games iAds Extension)

I noticed that when a user clicks the iad, interacts with it and then returns to the game there is a long delay with a black screen as Starling recovers a Stage3D context.

I would like to be able to show some sort of loading screen during this time, but everything I try doesn't seem to work. 
Does anyone have a suggestion how to implement this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory, haven't tested it but it should work.

Listen for `Event.ACTIVATE`. This should trigger when the iAd is closed. It's also triggered a lot of other times so we need to make sure that we check for this black screen, to do this we can simply have this inside the event handler:

```
private function _onActivateHandler(e:Event):void
{
    if (starling.context.driverInfo.indexOf("Disposed") != -1)
    {
        this.addChild(loadingTextOrBitmapEtcEtc);

        starling.stage3D.addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, this._onContext3DCreateHandler);
    }
}

private function _onContext3DCreateHandler(e:Event):void
{
    starling.stage3D.removeEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, this._onContext3DCreateHandler);

    this.removeChild(loadingTextOrBitmapEtcEtc);
}
```